# How to open the built-in task manager when it's replaced by Process Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, process-explorer

I want to open the built-in task manager **with Process Explorer's `Replace Task Manager` option checked**. I've tried:

- Running `taskmgr.exe` from the run dialog. PE was opened instead.
- Creating a copy of `taskmgr.exe` in the same folder. Then run it. The built-in task manager was opened, but not working properly(its window was blank).
- Creating a symbolic link (using `mklink`) of `taskmgr.exe` in the same folder. Then run it. PE was opened instead.

Is there any other method I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Process Hacker offers the ability to *Start Task Manager* in the Tools menu. If that would be OK with you, you might want to look for the same feature in PE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- The way that Process Explorer takes over from Task Manager is by adding a registry value:

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe\Debugger

This means whenever you start an executable named 'taskmgr.exe', start whatever is specified in this value instead. So moving task manager to a different directory does not work.

- Renaming taskmgr.exe to something else seems to break something
  within Task Manager. That why you see an empty window. That's a
  rather odd behavior, normally it is no problem to rename an
  executable.

  The renamed task manager behaves rather odd. Even if started from a medium integrity level, it automatically runs in high integrity level and it can not be killed even with local system privileges.

So for now, I don't see a way to have Process Explorer as default task manager and be able to run task manager at the same time.

The workaround is not too bad:

In Process Explorer, untick 'Options - Replace Task Manager', then run 'taskmgr.exe' and tick 'Options - Replace Task Manager' again.

Alternatively you can create a batch-file that removes that registry setting, starts task manager and puts the setting back in:

```
 reg.exe delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe" /v Debugger /f
 start taskmgr.exe
 reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ /d "C:\PATHTO\PROCEXP.EXE" /f
```

The only problem with this batch is that you need to run it as an elevated administrator, so when creating a shortcut for it, specify to run it as an administrator. As a normal user you cannot change those registry settings.

Comment: Unticking the option is exactly what I don't want to do. Creating a batch is better, I'll try it.

Comment: Does not work for me with lastest Process Explorer

Comment: @RobertNiestroj - Works fine for me on `Windows 10 - 1909` and `Process Explorer v16.30`

Comment: For some reason I can't use either solution. Both still will open process explorer. I think it got stuck on it now ...

Answer (score -1):

Because it is impossible then we sway with the wind:
1.Open sysinternal version of taskmaneger ie. Processs Explorer.
2.Click the replacement: Options/Replace Task Manager
3.Open normal taskmanager by Winflag+R: C:\WINDOWS\System32\Taskmgr.exe
4.Do your thing
5.Reclick Options/Replace Task Manager

Comment: The OP says [“Unticking the ['Options → Replace Task Manager'\] option is exactly what I don't want to do.”](https://superuser.com/q/661017/354511#comment840333_665202) and [“But my goal is to not uncheck that option, …”](https://superuser.com/q/661017/354511#comment834196_661019).

Comment: I very much understand the point. But in my case which was exactly the same(I would not like not like to tick that) as Op had I ended up to do it because I was able to return  the Process Explorer function(which I love) in the same session. So for any one who is wondering if Process Explorer can be swithed to Normal Task Manager and back on the fly in same session the answer is: yes.

Answer (score -2):

**RUnning Taskmanager from Run**

Click the Start button then the All Programs folder. Under the Accessories folder click the Run command. You can also press they Windows Key + R on your keyboard or enable the Run command in your Start Menu. Finally, simply type “taskmgr” and hit Enter.

**Running Taskmanager from shortcut**
Or you may create a shortcut. Right-click on your desktop and choose New then click Shortcut. A new window will pop up. Browse to the same path as above, C:\Windows\System32. Scroll down until you see taskmgr.exe, highlight it, and then click OK. Click Next, type a name for your shortcut, and finally click Finish

Comment: Do you mean "uncheck the 'Replace Task Manager' option"?

Comment: yes. Try unchecking it.

Comment: But my goal is to not uncheck that option, because I use PE most times.

Comment: Oh..sorry.. Click the Start button then the All Programs folder. Under the Accessories folder click the Run command. You can also press they Windows Key + R on your keyboard or enable the Run command in your Start Menu. Finally, simply type “taskmgr” and hit Enter.

Comment: Or you may create a shortcut. Right-click on your desktop and choose New then click Shortcut. A new window will pop up. Browse to the same path as above, C:\Windows\System32. Scroll down until you see taskmgr.exe, highlight it, and then click OK. Click Next, type a name for your shortcut, and finally click Finish.

Comment: I tried both, they didn't work.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: They opened Process Explorer. Typing `taskmgr` in the run dialog and creating a shortcut of `taskmgr.exe`, both of them opened Process Explorer.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work.